# IE and Safari add extra padding

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, padding

Since I'm fairly sure this is an instance of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/188613) I'm going to start with the *Y*. I have an image that's 300px wide, and I want three links underneath the image, flush against it. The last link needs to grow in size to fill the remaining space.

Now for the *X*. The markup I have works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE and Safari the third link is 2px too large.

For your copy/pasting pleasure:

```
<head>    
    <style type="text/css">
        .breakfast
        {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            padding: 10px 25px;
            margin: 5px -5px;
            font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: #d9e021;
            color: #00add0;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .breakfast:hover
        {
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #bdc400;
            color: #0198b6;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="my_awesome_image.jpg" width="300"
            height="190" alt="My awesome image." />
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -5px;">
        <a class="breakfast" href="#">BOSTON </a>
        <a class="breakfast" href="#">CHICAGO </a>
        <a class="breakfast" href="#" style="width: 38px;">DC </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

Or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/pX6S7/1/), graciously provided by Mr.Lister.

So the final link, "DC" sticks out beyond the image by 2px in Safari and IE. If I shave off 2px, it's too short in Chrome and Firefox. I also tried adding padding to the left and right  of the link but same deal.

Comment: mhm, you could add browser detection then if its a major bug for you. i am not aware of any other workaround

Comment: I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/pX6S7/1/). Next time, you make it, OK?

Comment: @MrLister thanks, but is a [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22754/188613) no longer acceptable?

Comment: A fiddle is much easier to work with. Now I don't have a solution, but I did find a workaround. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pX6S7/2/). Just give the div underneath the picture the same width and a background color, and don't mind about the width of its content.

Comment: @MrLister thanks for playing with it, but that makes the hover effects go all screwy. I'm not particular arsed either way, but the design team won't be happy with me. :(

Comment: reset your CSS before coding CSS

Comment: Crikey, the hover. I hadn't thought about that at all, sorry. Stand by.

Comment: @l2aelba CSS resets are nasty hacks that cause more trouble than they're worth.

Comment: @MrLister Agree, ok next project :D

Comment: @l2aelba Seriously, which property did you want to reset? What is it that differs between IE/Safari on the one hand and Firefox/Chrome on the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another fiddle, that works in all four browsers. And opera, for good measure.

I did have to give `width:290px` to the container `div` and `width:33px; float:right` to the last `a`.

http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/pX6S7/13/

Still not sure though why this works, while the original doesn't. Sorry. Oh, and the widths may sound random, but that is caused by the 5px and -5px margins. They do add up.

Comment: So this is just some weird cross-browser thing and I'm not losing my mind? That's a relief.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fiddle for you

http://jsfiddle.net/5ve6U/3/

Dont be confused about the different width/height of your image container in this fiddle, i made it only, to see the full width with  the help of a border

only resetet the body margins/padding and change your /padding/margin

```
.breakfast {
    padding: 10px 24px;
    margin: 5px -3px;
}
```

it works fine for me in IE

Comment: But how can you see how wide the div is? With a 300px image next to it, that would be much easier.